# what is api for "page as copy" in oracle apex?

Tags: api, oracle-apex

what is the sql api to copy page from 1 application to an other in same workspace?
I want api for "page as copy" in oracle apex page development.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no published APIs to copy pages, this must be done within the Application Builder.

Any documented APIs may be found at
https://apex.oracle.com/api